# How can I code loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with the loop in python. I want create a list x[X0,X1,....Xn], with this algorithm:

```
X1=X0-(5+X0*2); X2=X1-(5+X1*2);.....
```

I try this but the result is not correct.

```
a=list(np.empty(10))
a[0]=1
for i in range(10):
        a.append(a[i]-(5+a[i]*2))
        print (a [i])
```

If you manually iterating the result gives:

```
[1,-6,1,-6, ....]
```

But after loop it gives:

```
[1,-1.29074375768e-231,2.19254982219e-314,.....]
```

The loop are easy in C but I did not understand the functioning in Python, if you have an idea ?

Comment: That is clearly not the same formula - why would you expect the same result?

Comment: sorry, I corrected.

Comment: You still need to describe how it is not working. What is the output you receive and what did you expect?

Comment: The value is x[0]=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `list(np.empty(10))` doesn't do what you think it does. You expect it to return a list with 10 zeros, but it actually returns a list of 10 "random" numbers (actually, it returns a list of 10 uninitialized values).

From numpy [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html):

> **empty**, unlike zeros, **does not set the array values to zero**, and may
>   therefore be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the
>   user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be used
>   with caution.

(emphasize mine)

Instead, you should simply create a list with a single element, `1`, and go on from there:

```
a = [1]
for i in range(10):
    a.append(a[i] - (5 + a[i] * 2))
print(a)
# [1, -6, 1, -6, 1, -6, 1, -6, 1, -6, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to start your list with anything more than the single element. In C, you have to decide up front how many elements you want in your list, but that's not the case in Python, so doing `list(np.empty(10))` creates a list with ten pointless elements in it that are just getting in your way.

```
a = [1] # This creates a list that starts off with the element 1.
for i in range(10):
    a.append(a[i] - (5 + a[i] * 2))
    print (a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on functions, lists and for loops in python, as from your question it appears that you do not understand them very well.

There are several reasons why your code isn't currently working, but they are all easy fixed.

Firstly, you initiate a list with a numpy list, which is unnecessary.

```
a = list(np.empty(10))
```

can simply become

```
a = list()
```

or even simpler,

```
a = []
```

Next up, not an error but a suggestion,

```
a[0] = 1
```

can be removed and instead when you initialize the list, place one as the first item

```
a = [1]
```

after that, your code should work. So in summary:

```
n = 10 # or whatever number you want
a = [1]
for i in range(n - 1):
    a.append(a[i] - (5 + a[i] * 2))
```

and if you want it as a function:

```
def formula_list(n):
    a = [1]
    for i in range(n - 1):
        a.append(a[i] - (5 + a[i] * 2))
    return a
```

Comment: why the downvote? - if my answer does not help you please tell me why

Comment: @SilvioMayolo fixed that now. Im guessing OP downvoted because I said he needed to look at loops

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this answer simply throws a working code at OP. It is more beneficial (both for OP and for future readers) to include an explanation **why** OPs code doesn't work.

Comment: @DeepSpace ill improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

They way you have arranged your equation will constantly print out -6, and 1, therefore:

```
a = [1]

iti = 0

while(True):
    thing = a[iti]-(5+(a[iti]*2))
    a.append(thing)
    iti+=1
    print(thing)
```

I chose not to use the for loop to show a more understandable example, but you can still use that if you like.